# Remove :hover effects from :after content

Tags: html, css

I want to remove hover effect from the the content added using the css selector `:after`.
My code is as below i want to remove hover effect( which is underline) from `>`

**HTML**

```
<ul class="path_string_ul">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>MENU</li>
    <li>SUB-MENU</li>
    <li>SUB-SUB-MENU></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.path_string_ul li{
            display:inline-block;
            list-style:none;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .path_string_ul li:hover{
            cursor:pointer;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .path_string_ul li:after{
            content:'>';
            margin:0 10px;
            pointer-events: none;
            text-decoration:none !important; /*Not working*/
        }
        .path_string_ul li:hover:after{
            text-decoration:none !important; /*Not working*/
        }
        .path_string_ul li:last-child:after{
            content:none;
        }
```

Here is [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fS9E5/) link

Comment: @undefined i don't understand? plz explain how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the default `display` property of the pseudo-element generated by `:after` selector is `inline` so the `text-decoration` property is not applied to the element. You can set the `display` property to `inline-block`:

```
.path_string_ul li:after {
     content:'>';
     margin:0 10px;
     pointer-events: none;
  +  display: inline-block;
     text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `float:right` for the `:after` so that `text-decoration:underline` is not affected.

```
.path_string_ul li:after {
   content:'>';
   float:right;
   height:100%;
   margin-left:10px;
   pointer-events: none;                
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/fS9E5/1/)